# MathJax not displaying dynamically added(using js) matrix properly

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I am new to MathJax and just started learning it. I am trying to display a matrix by adding it to the page using js. But it is not being rendered properly. My code for putting the matrix is:

```
function displayTransformationMatrix()
{
    var matrix = "$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & vx \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & vy \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & vz \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$"
    var tranMat = document.getElementById("transformMatrix");
    tranMat.innerHTML = matrix;
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, 'transformMatrix']);
}
```

Here `transformMatrix` is a `div`, `vx, vy, vz` are variables. The matrix is rendered properly when the same text is added directly to the div, but if done in this way it gives this:[image]

What mistake am I doing? I have just started learning MathJax, so please understand if there is some silly mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript `\` is reserved as an escape character, if you want it in a string, you have to double it and write `\\` instead (see log in your console)

```js
function displayTransformationMatrix()
{
    var matrix = "$$\\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & vx \\\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & vy \\\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & vz \\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\end{bmatrix}$$"
    var tranMat = document.getElementById("transformMatrix");
    tranMat.innerHTML = matrix;
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, 'transformMatrix']);
    console.log(matrix);
}

displayTransformationMatrix();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_SVG-full" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <span id="transformMatrix"></span>
```